# 'await' has no effect on this type of expression

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I saw similar threads on this but still can't be sure if I'm doing something wrong or the warning is misplaced.

I have a component with tryLogin function that calls an outer function:

```
export const Login: React.FunctionComponent<LoginProps> = ({ login }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const tryLogin = async (payload: LoginPayload) => {
    await login(payload); // This line gives the warning
    navigate('./home');
  };
```

The outer function is a class named 'login', in a store, on which I receive the warning. I'm using await here because I'd like to navigate only after login is done.
The class:

```
  public login = async (payload: LoginPayload): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const {
        data: { accessToken },
      } = await login({ payload });
      this.authResponse = { accessToken };
      console.log({ accessToken });
      this.rootStore.main.setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      this.rootStore.main.setLoading(false);
      console.error('error', err);
    }
  };
```

The function returns a promise and I'm awaiting it inside tryLogin, so am I doing something wrong to receive this warning?

Comment: Inside of `public login`, what is `login` resolving to? Also, make sure you indicate exactly which line is having the error.

Comment: @crashmstr the inner login resolves to an object, yes I'll edit the line with warning now

Comment: What is `LoginProps`? Likely that definition does not declare `login` as returning `Promise<void>`. I would also advise to not give something the same name from different scopes but are used together. Becomes very confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much you were right that was the case